# get json response from neo4j using python

Tags: python, json, neo4j

I want to convert the results of cypher queries in neo4j into a JSON format.

I am currently using the neo4j library to connect and query the graph. I can, but converting the results into JSON is cumbersome and hence this question.

Here is my current code:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
from config import bolt_url,auth_id,auth_pass

driver = GraphDatabase.driver(bolt_url, auth=basic_auth(auth_id, auth_pass))
session = driver.session()

def get_some_data(limit=25) :
    query = 'MATCH (n:Person)--(m:Organization) \
            RETURN n,m LIMIT ' + str(limit)
    return session.run(query)

result_some_data = get_some_data(limit=1)
gen = result_some_data.records()

for record in gen :
    for k,v in record.items() :
        print('{',k,':',v,'}')
        print(v.get('name','meow'))

session.close
```

I get the following output :

```
{ n : <Node id=44567 labels={'Person'} properties={'name': 'ABC'}> }
ABC
{ m : <Node id=34745 labels={'Organization'} properties={'name': 'XYZ'}> }
XYZ
```

As you can see, the output is giving `Node` objects. I am able to get the 
`properties` but not the `labels` or `id`. I may be able to get the `id` and `labels`, but it gets much complex and much cumbersome.

Now the JSON format I need is very specific and I don't expect to get the results in that specific format.

Let's say this is the basic JSON format I need:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "columns": ["n", "m"],
        "data": [{
            "graph": {
                "nodes": [{
                    "id": "44567",
                    "labels": ["Person"],
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "ABC"
                    }
                }, {
                    "id": "34745",
                    "labels": ["Organization"],
                    "properties": {
                        "name": "ABC"
                }],
                "relationships": [{
                    "id": "1",
                    "type": "WorksIn",
                    "startNode": "44567",
                    "endNode": "34745",
                    "properties": {
                        "title": "CEO"
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }],
}
```

The code here, is not the code I am going to use in the future, it is just a demo code I wrote to ask this question.

So basically what I am asking here is a way to get the JSON response from neo4j, after running the cypher queries, rather than parsing the result and then generating a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean with cumbersome to get the labels and the id ... I mean, if you have a Node object o then the id is **o.id** and the labels are **o.labels**, no ?

Anyway, the issue is that Cypher can return quite a few different things (a table of discrete values, nodes, relationships, paths, a subgraph, ...) and when accessing the database through a driver it is you that has to determine what to do with the result. So you are given a result-set (which from the point of view of the database could contain anything) and have to do the post-processing yourself (since only you know what you actually asked for).

If you really want a JSON-like result, you could query the database through the HTTP endpoint. It will still require heavy processing from your end though.

Hope this helps (or at least explains why things are the way they are).

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 5):

```
import json 
def get_some_data(limit=25) :
    query = 'MATCH (n:Person)--(m:Organization) RETURN n,m LIMIT ' + str(limit)
    return session.run(query)

json_data = json.dumps(get_some_data(limit=1).data())
```

data() provides the records in json format recursively